# How do I add percentage to Report Viewer row

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc

I have a question about the visual studio report builder (rdlc files).
I have a row group with counts of records per doctor:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0G0k.png

The count of records is used in the first column. The column grouping repeats the "No" and "%" columns per "PatientComfort" value.
How do I get the percentage column to show the percentage of each "No" column per row?

I would want this type of thing:

```
              Comfort1         Comfort2      Comfort3
             No      %         No      %     No      %
Dr Smith     17      31%       34     62%     4      7%
Dr Jones     22      37%       15     25%    22     38%
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the denominator, you need to get the total for each doctor, so you have to specify the **Scope** of the aggregate used in the denominator. The **%** expression will look something like:

```
=Sum(Fields!no.Value) / Sum(Fields!no.Value, "doctor")
```

With an example based on your data:

[image]

I set up at test report as the following:

[image]

The **%** expression is the one specified above. This gives the correct results, give or take some rounding/sorting differences:

[image]

**Added after comment**

It sounds like you can just change the expression to:

```
=Count(Fields!no.Value) / Count(Fields!no.Value, "Endoscopist")
```

You're just changing the aggregate type from `Sum` to `Count`; you don't need to apply further aggregates to the `Count` value.

The principle, taking the current Scope aggregate and comparing it to a parent Scope, is still the same.

If you're still having issues please supply an example DataSet definition with a few lines of data along with your desired results.

Comment: I included a screenshot with the field names in the original post. The complication is that the "No" value is a count. I tried translating your code to =Sum(Count(Fields!ID.Value)) / Sum(Count(Fields!ID.Value), "Endoscopist") but that doesn't work.

Comment: Can't do an aggregate function within an aggregate function.

Comment: I have added a few more details which will hopefully help your issue.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks very much. I had no idea you could ignore the count function and it would still work.